# Collections with generic objects

Tags: c#, oop, collections

There is a method that takes a list of base objects as a parameter.

```
abstract class Base {}
class MyClass:Base {}
//...
void Method(List<Base> list) {}
```

When I`m calling that method, I want to pass list of derived objects.

```
var derivedList = new List<MyClass>();
Method(derivedList);
```

But I cannot do that because collection of derived is not the same as collection of base objects.
What is the best practice to handle this situation? Now I'm using my extension .ToBase() where I create new collection, but I think there is nicer solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make your `Method` generic:

```
public void Method<T>(List<T> list) where T : Base
{
    //Do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If the method is only *reading* the values, it could be declared as:

```
void Method(IEnumerable<Base> list)
```

that way, your calling code will work fine in C# 4 / .NET 4 without any changes. In .NET 3.5 you could use

```
Method(derivedList.Cast<Base>());
```

If your method is *adding* values to the list, then generic covariance won't and *shouldn't* work. After all, you wouldn't want a reference to an instance of some *other* class derived from `Base` to be added to your `List<MyClass>`, would you?

Making `Method` generic (as suggested by Klaus) will work in various situations too, but can also make the code more complicated. It's hard to say whether or not this is a good approach without knowing what your method does... although it's definitely worth trying.

Answer (score 4):

Co-/contra-variance is implemented in C#4.0 which will allow you to directly pass your `List<MyClass>` in a method requiring `List<Base>` without more work.

In C#3.5, you can use the `Cast<T>()` extension method to convert an enumerable of one type to another, which will allow you to convert it to the base type (with the cost of a cast for each entry). It seems that you've already done that with your extension method `.ToBase()`

Comment: Variance only applies to interfaces, and even then only to interfaces meeting some conditions. List is a class, and IList is not covariant or contravariant.

Answer (score 0):

The is because `List<MyClass>` is not a `List<Base>`.

What you can do is:

```
Method(derivedList.Cast<Base>().ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a nicer solution, given the existing Method signature. What you're trying to do *can* be accomplished with primitive arrays, and everyone regrets it. The thing is that if you pass someone a `List<Base>`, then it *should* be allowed for them to place in `Base` or anything derived from it. But they can't, because it's really a `List<MyClass>`. It would break a *lot* of things if this were allowed. Making a new collection is the best way to go.